# How to use kartik yii2-export with model in array type

Tags: yii2

I have query like this in my controller

```
$dataPendaftar = Pendaftar::find()
            ->select(['pendaftar.*','user.*'])
            ->from('pendaftar') 
            -> leftJoin('user', 'user.id=pendaftar.id_user_pendaftar')
            ->asArray()
            ->all();

    return $this->render('index', [
        'dataPendaftar' =>  $dataPendaftar,
    ]);
```

and in my view, i try to use kartik yii2-export widget, like this

```
$gridColumns= [
        'nik_pendaftar',
        'tanggal_lahir',
        'email',


    ];
    echo ExportMenu::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataPendaftar,
        'columns' => $gridColumns,
        'fontAwesome' => true,
    ]);
```

but i got error

> Call to a member function getModels() on array

is it possible to use kartik yii2-export widget with model in array instead dataProvider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExportMenu:$dataProvider` needs to be instance of `DataProviderInterface`, but you're passing array of models (this is what `all()` returns). Try this:

```
$dataPendaftar = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => Pendaftar::find()
        ->select(['pendaftar.*','user.*'])
        ->from('pendaftar')
        ->leftJoin('user', 'user.id=pendaftar.id_user_pendaftar')
]);

return $this->render('index', [
    'dataPendaftar' =>  $dataPendaftar,
]);
```

Or if you really want to use result of your query, then use [`ArrayDataProvider`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-arraydataprovider):

```
$dataPendaftar = Pendaftar::find()
        ->select(['pendaftar.*','user.*'])
        ->from('pendaftar') 
        ->leftJoin('user', 'user.id=pendaftar.id_user_pendaftar')
        ->asArray()
        ->all();

return $this->render('index', [
    'dataPendaftar' => new ArrayDataPrivider([
        'allModels' => $dataPendaftar,
    ]),
]);
```